# what would be the highest temp limit switch i can run on a colman 3800a816 furnace

Tags: furnace

Put in new 150 degree switches but it seems to not be hot enough would it be ok to go with 200degree or what would you suggest

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm not an expert, but boy! does that sound like a bad idea. Boosting from 150°F to 200°F is a drastic change when it comes to water temperatures, and hot-rodding a home heating furnace is a great way to make your life entertaining, in an extremely unpleasant way.

Answer (score 1):

## NO.

You should only replace the high limit switch with an identical replacement. If the limit is opening, there's a problem that needs to be addressed.  Figure out why the furnace is overheating, and fix *that* problem.

Dirty filters, or restricted air flow, are the most common problems.